# omitempty does not work in encoding/xml when using pointers?

Tags: go

I am consuming a REST API that returns XML and am trying to Unmarshal the XML and am having issues that appear that the `omitempty` is not working. Here is an example of a working XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<customer uri="/api/customers/339/" id="339">
    <name>
        <first>Firstname</first>
        <last>Lastname</last>
    </name>
    <email>myemail@example.com</email>
    <billing>
        <address>
            <address1>123 Main St.</address123>
            <address2></address2>
            <city>Nowhere</city>
            <state>IA</state>
            <country>USA</country>
            <zip>12345</zip>
        </address>
    </billing>
</customer>
```

Here is an example of a "bad" record

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<customer uri="/api/customers/6848/" id="6848">
    <name>
        <first>Firstname</first>
        <last>Lastname</last>
    </name>
    <email/>
    <billing/>
</customer>
```

Now I have my structs set up like the following:

```
 type Customer struct {
     ID      int      `xml:"id,attr"`
     Name    *Name    `xml:"name,omitempty"`
     Billing *Billing `xml:"billing,omitempty"`
 }

 type Billing struct {
     Address *Address `xml:"address,omitempty"`
 }

 type Address struct {
     address_1 string `xml:",omitempty"`
     address_2 string `xml:",omitempty"`
     city      string `xml:",omitempty"`
     postal    string `xml:",omitempty"`
     country   string `xml:",omitempty"`
 }

 type Name struct {
     first, last string
 }
```

Reading through all of the records it works when the XML follows the pattern of the first example `<billing></billing>` but when it hits a record that has something like `<billing/>` it throws the following error: `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

Can someone help me figure out what's going on and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably misunderstanding what `,omitempty` means. It takes effect when *marshalling* data, only. If you unmarshal `<billing/>` onto a pointer field with `,omitempty`, it will still initialize the field. Then, since the XML element is empty, the fields of `Billing` itself won't be set. In practice, if you assume that `customer.Billing != nil` means `customer.Billing.Address != nil`, you'll get the observed panic.

Note: http://play.golang.org/p/dClkfOVLXh